# PHP simpleload xml value

Tags: php, xml, load

Consider the following xml document. I need to get the value of "Kolumbi". It is always 2nd in  line, always with Language='sqi'. Is there any way to do this without looping in a foreach? The reason I'm asking is because I have this in a lot of cases, and I think its just slowing down the system by looping so much. Its just a translation xml, giving different values for different languages. Imagine the possibilities and loops I need to run for each word. Is there a way to get it with a variable, ie category->texts->text->?language=sqi->value or whatnot?

Thanks in advance.

```
<Category id="274">
    <Texts>
        <Text Language="def">
            <Value>Colombia</Value>
        </Text>
        <Text Language="sqi">
            <Value>Kolumbi</Value>
        </Text>
        <Text Language="en">
            <Value>Colombia</Value>
        </Text>
    </Texts>
</Category>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `simplexml_load_string`.

```
$xml_string = '<Category id="274">
  <Texts>
     <Text Language="def">
        <Value>Colombia</Value>
     </Text>
     <Text Language="sqi">
        <Value>Kolumbi</Value>
     </Text>
     <Text Language="en">
        <Value>Colombia</Value>
     </Text>
  </Texts>
 </Category>';
```

`$xml_array = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);`

`echo $xml_array->Texts->Text[1]->Value;`

[Codepad](http://codepad.org/V0R1ILjk)

**Note:** As you said here `kolumbi` will always be 2nd.

Comment: Ya it will if you have xml file use that !!